# Can't show date of a search result in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm doing a search with my backend with a service in angular, in my html show that information, but in the input date don't show information, I trying various ways but the date don't show, in my backend the required format date is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"

How can I show the date in my input? if all other data does show

Service

```
 update(heroe:Heroe){
    return this._http.put<Heroe>(this.urlApi + "/updateHeroe/" + heroe.id, heroe);
  }
```

TS

```
 this.heroesService.searchById(this.heroesService.idHeroe)
    .subscribe(result=>(this.selected= result));
```

then the input in which I want to show the search date
HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput value="{{ selected.date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}" [matDatepicker]="picker [(ngModel)]="selected.date"><mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify your question a bit more? What is the expected result compared to the actual result?

Comment: There is no JSON involved here. Angular's `HttpClient` service does the conversion from JSON to `Heroe` for you. As far as I recall, you shouldn't be using both `value` and `ngModel`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding browser will use the local date format. Don't think it's possible to change. You could of course use a custom date picker.

[check this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qlzcv6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: That's not the same thing. The OP is using a `mat-datepicker`, which is an angular-material component -- one of those custom date pickers you talk about.